# Need to have multiple condition in this code

Tags: javascript

I would like to know why this code works:

```
switch(element.type) {
    case 'input':
    case 'textarea':
        type = 'innerHTML';
        break;
    case 'file':
        type = 'src';
        break;
}

var div = document.getElementById(element.id)||null;
if(div!=null){
    if(type=='innerHTML') div.innerHTML = element.value;
    if(type=='src') div.src = element.value;
};
```

And this one doesn't ?

```
switch(element.type) {
    case 'input':
    case 'textarea':
        type = 'innerHTML';
        break;
    case 'file':
        type = 'src';
        break;
}

var div = document.getElementById(element.id)||null;
if(div!=null){ div.type = element.value;};
```

Anyone for pointing me the error ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? It Does Nothing? Show an error? Fails to display tomorrows' lottery numbers?

Comment: It does nothing. No output or error. Just do nothing.

Comment: I'm trying to make this line dynamic `div.type = element.value;`. So replace `type` during the `switch`.

Comment: You're trying to use a variable you've set to access a property using dot notation..  It doesn't work like that.

Comment: @teamo might be because they don't have the same code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last sample you're accessing property `type` of `div`.

To make it work change it to:

```
div[type] = element.value;
```